# Counterclockwise Arrows emoji displays wrong on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, unicode, emoji

The [Counterclockwise Arrows emoji (U+1F504)](https://emojipedia.org/counterclockwise-arrows-button/) is supposed to look like this:

[image: Counterclockwise Arrows emoji]

Instead, it displays as the [end arrow emoji (U+1F51A)](https://emojipedia.org/end-arrow/):

[image: End Arrow emoji]

The following list are the unicode characters in question:

1. (counterclockwise arrows)
2. (end arrow)

Here is a screenshot of this list from Windows 11:

[image: Windows 11 Emojis]

I have a Windows 10 machine where these characters render fine; here is a screenshot of this list from Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10 Emojis]

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: The lower arrow in your post is all that is available on my Windows 11 machine.

Comment: Same font on both PC's?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik good thought.  as far as I can tell, they're both using Segoe UI, but unicode characters seem to render quite differently.  How would I get more information on this?

Comment: Try one of the other available fonst, or install another. You might use the excellent (and free) tool, *FontViewOK*, https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/FontViewOK , to see how a character set looks. You can substitute text (containing the counterclockwise arrow) for the default text. Also try Windows Character Map.

Comment: Confirmed. The "Counterclockwise Arrows" emoji https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%F0%9F%94%84/ is broken at the Windows 11 system level. It doesn't matter what font (Calibri, Consolas, etc) or application (Notepad, Word, Chrome) you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed as of Version 22H2 of Windows 11.  Here is a screenshot of the two emojis as of this version:

[image: Counterclockwise emoji vs end arrow emoji on Windows 11]